# Flutter only finds Firestore documents created manually in the Firestore UI

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a document count from a Firestore collection that I am creating dynamically with the following code. The collections and documents seem to be created in Firestore successfully, and I can view them in the Firestore UI. Also, I'm **NOT** seeing any messages like "*This document does not exist and will not appear in queries or snapshots*". I believe the docs actually exist.

[image]

Here's the db method I am using to create the docs.

```
addParkRiderData(String park, Rider rider) async {
    DateTime $now = DateTime.now();
    var formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String $today = formatter.format($now);
    int $updated = $now.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    String uid = replaceWithAt(rider.name!);

    await _db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('runs')
        .doc(park)
        .set({'created': $updated}, SetOptions(merge: true));

    await _db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('runs')
        .doc(park)
          .collection($today)
          .doc()
          .set({'created': $updated}).catchError((e) => print(e));
}
```

Here's the db service Stream where I am trying to get the docs.

```
Stream getMyParkRuns(String park, riderName) {
    DateTime $now = DateTime.now();
    var formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String $today = formatter.format($now);
    String uid = replaceWithAt(riderName);
    return _db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('runs')
        .doc(park)
        .collection($today)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

Here's the StreamBuilder where I am displaying the document size.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: db.getMyParkRuns(
    widget.user.park!, widget.user.username),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var runs = snapshot.data.size.toString();
      return Container(
        child: Text(runs, 
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6!.copyWith(fontSize: 60)));
    }
    return Text('0');
  },
),
```

*widget.user.park* is populated by a field value in the user document that I am certain is correct. **Here's the weird thing...if I manually create a new park document in the Firestore UI** with a new collection with the correctly formatted date, then change the widget.user.park value to match either in the Firestore UI or by updating it with a hard coded value in the StreamBuilder parameter, the StreamBuilder works perfectly. So this is only happening for documents that are created by by my addParkRiderData() db method. I have also converted the db method to a Future and the ui code to a FutureBuilder, and had the same results. But since the docs seemingly exist in the Firestore UI, am I starting to think the db is corrupted. The only thing I can think of to try is creating new root collection or new db.

Comment: Try printing `$today` and see if `0` is prefixed if the number is less than `10`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Josteve. print($today) returns `flutter: 2022-01-23` as expected. If I create a new document in the Firestore UI, or delete the programmatically created one and manually replace it with a doc with the same id value, and then add the collection with the $today value and create a new doc in that collection everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being caused by leading whitespace on my park variable that I was passing to my addParkRiderData db function. Once I added .trim() to park everything worked fine. Trim your strings!